# Getting the error 'input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`'

Tags: reactjs

Here is a snippet of my code, I'm getting the error "input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`". What am I doing wrong?

```
<div className="modal-body">
    <p>{children}</p>

    <InputClient>

        <p>Enter Client Name</p>

        <InputText type="text" value={ clientName } onChange={this.handleChangeInputClientName} />

    </InputClient>

    <InputStockItem>

        <p>Enter Stock Item</p>

        <InputText type="text" value={ itemName } onchange={this.handleChangeInputStockItemName} />

    </InputStockItem>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your InputText component? The error indicates you have an <input> tag somewhere with children. That tag should be self closing and not have any children.

Comment: const InputText = styled.input.attrs({
    className: 'form-control',
})`
    margin: 0px;

`

Comment: Consider adding a full codesandbox example that demonstrates the error.
https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Answer (score 1):

`input` cannot render child elements. Instead you should wrap your `input`'s in a `label` tag and write the labels above the `input`'s. You should rewrite your code like the below.

```
 <div className="modal-body">
                <p>{children}</p>
            <label>
             Enter Client Name
             <InputClient>
                <InputText
                    type="text"
                    value={ clientName }
                    onChange={this.handleChangeInputClientName}
             />
             </InputClient>
             </label>
             <label>
             Enter Stock Item
             <InputStockItem>
                <InputText
                        type="text"
                        value={ itemName }
                        onchange={this.handleChangeInputStockItemName}
                />
             </InputStockItem>
           </label>
</div>
```

There is more information [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6241)

Comment: I tried adding the <Label> outside the InputText however I still am getting the same error!

Comment: What do your `InputStockItem` and `InputClient` look like? If their `inputs` then it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it! I had accidentally declared the InputClient and InputStockItem components as follows :

```
const InputClient = styled.input.attrs({

})`
    margin: 0px;

`
```

and

```
const InputStockItem = styled.input.attrs({

})`
    margin: 0px;

`
```

It was a silly mistake on my part for what should have been something like this  :

```
const InputClient = styled.div.attrs({

})`
    margin: 0px;

`
```

And

```
const InputStockItem = styled.div.attrs({

})`
    margin: 0px;

`
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: So it was the nested `inputs` after all.